# Interrupting a loop

Tags: powershell

I just do my first steps with powershell and have a questions about a loop I'm using in a script:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 100; $i++){
    $res = Test-Connection $IP -count 1 -Quiet
    ...do something more
    start-sleep -seconds 30
}
```

This script does not allow to close the windows form (it's started from a GUI) or interrupt the loop. Is there a way to do so? Sometimes I want to stop the loop manually.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to use powershell flow control.
With [powershell flow control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/06-flow-control?view=powershell-7.2) you are able to manually control loops in powershell.
Let me give you an example:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 100; $i++){
    $res = Test-Connection $IP -count 1 -Quiet
    ...do something more

    if ($res -eq $anyresultyouwouldexpect) {
       break ##with **break** you interupt the loop completely- You script 
             ## would continue after the loop.
    }
    

}
```

There are also flow control statements like **continue** to jump into the next iteration loop. It is depending on what you need in your case.

Comment: Thank you that put me in the right way.